# The method 'delete' isn't defined for the class 'AppJsImpl'

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code

I develop the flutter app connected with Firebase.
The app work well on mobile devices, but when i try to build web i get this error:

```
/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database_web-0.1.2/lib/src/interop/app.dart:35:59: Error: The method 'delete' isn't defined for the class 'AppJsImpl'.
- 'AppJsImpl' is from 'package:firebase_database_web/src/interop/app_interop.dart' ('/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database_web-0.1.2/lib/src/interop/app_interop.dart').
package:firebase_database_web/…/interop/app_interop.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'delete'.
 Future delete() => core_interop.handleThenable(jsObject.delete());
```

I tried to put  `firebase_database_web: ^0.1.2+1` in pubspec.yaml, but error is still here.
Did someone have the same problem, and how are you fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tackled the issue by adding a row in the "app_interop.dart" file.

Before:

```
@JS('App')
abstract class AppJsImpl extends core_interop.AppJsImpl {
  external DatabaseJsImpl database(String? databaseURL);
}
```

After:

```
@JS('App')
abstract class AppJsImpl extends core_interop.AppJsImpl {
  external DatabaseJsImpl database(String? databaseURL);
  external dynamic delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest version of firebase_database_web to your pubspec.yaml

Fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).